# change device orientation compatible for ios6 and ios5

Tags: ios5, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I NEED: rotate device programmatically from portrait to landscape compatible for iOS6 and iOS5.
THE PROBLEM: I cannot use `[UIDevice setOrientation]` function on ios6.

WHAT I HAVE: the code for iOS6:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

the code for iOS5:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

So, I need write the code that rotate on iOS5:

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        // [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation] - I cannot use it
        // ???
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by set Status bar orientation, try execute in code:

```
[[sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

and when you need portrait mode, set status bar to `setStatusBarHidden:NO`and again set statusbar orientation to portrait `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`.